# Custom output folder in eclipse without another source folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to customize the output folder in eclipse. But the only way i know to do this in eclipse is creating another source folder.
Ex: I have the source folder src.
I had to create src, src/action and src/model in order to customize the output folder of src/action and src/model.

Eclipse displays the source folders in a way that i didn't like, is there another way to customize the output folder?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve, with more detail in the example?

Comment: What I'm trying do archive is do not change the way the project is displayed, because my team "didn't think it was intuitive".                 For example, if the tree structure of the project was only src, now it is src/, src/action and src/model.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify either one output folder for all your source folders, or separate source folder for each of the source folders. But you can't specify different output folders for sub packages within one source folder.

Comment: Can I develop a custom builder? Is it possible?

Comment: You could implement a builder, but I'd say you should not do that for quite large number of reasons that go well beyond your original question. However you can implement your own content provider for the Project Explorer view and present your folders any way you want (not like that would make any sense either, but you could do that).